# How could I get a hex code when I give a color name

Tags: ruby, colors, hex

I'm making a telegram bot and I would like for it to be able to give a hex code against a color name. I know there are a heck of a lot of rgb colors but I also know there is a wikipedia article with known color names and hex codes, if I could be able to get the pages as a json it would help. Also, if the json says hex code = color name how can I invert that? How can I search by the value and not the name?

Comment: I think you can find API's for that or just create a huge hash constant key-value pairs yourself using internet info. These seems like the easiest solutions to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are fine. If you're looking for a gem that's already done the work for you, though, take a look at [Color](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/color/). Its [`Color::CSS[]`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/color/Color/CSS#[]-class_method) method looks up a color by name and returns a Color::RGB object, which in turn has [`hex`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/color/Color/RGB#hex-instance_method) and [`html`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/color/Color/RGB#html-instance_method) methods:

```
require "color"

aliceblue = Color::CSS["aliceblue"]
puts aliceblue.hex
# => f0f8ff
puts aliceblue.html
# => #f0f8ff
```

Color::RGB also has a [`by_hex`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/color/Color/RGB#by_hex-class_method) static method, which will return a named Color::RGB object for the given hex code. The [`name`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/color/Color#name-instance_method) method returns the name (if it has one):

```
require "color"

mystery_color = Color::RGB.by_hex("#ffefd5")
puts mystery_color.name
# => papayawhip
```

You can see it in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/EqualReasonableSpellchecker (If you get an error the first time you hit the run button, hit it again. repl.it sometimes has trouble with loading gems the first time.)

Comment: Thanks! If the color asked is not a valid name, will the bot die? I think so? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: If you give an invalid name to `Color::CSS[]`, it will return `nil`, so you need to be sure to handle that. How you do that depends on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own Hash then [Hash#invert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-invert) it:

```
color_to_hex = { red: 'ff0000', green: '00ff00', blue: '0000ff' }
hex_to_color = color_to_hex.invert

color_to_hex[:red] #=> "ff0000"
hex_to_color['00ff00'] #=> :green
```

Or without creating the inverse hash:

```
colors_to_hex.key('00ff00') #=> :green
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following :

```
color_mappings = { 'yellow' => 'ffff00', 'red' => 'ff0000', 'green' => '00ff00', 'blue' => '0000ff' }
```

The hash can be inverted as follow :

```
inverted_color_mappings = color_mappings.invert
```

output :

```
{
    "ffff00" => "yellow",
    "ff0000" => "red",
    "00ff00" => "green",
    "0000ff" => "blue"
}


pattern = 'fff'
inverted_color_mappings.select{ |k,v| k[pattern] }
```

output :

```
{
    "ffff00" => "yellow"
}
```